# On The Subject of Rubik's Cube

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, rubiks-cube, twisty-puzzles

<sup>(This is part of a series of puzzles written for [Timwi](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/1480/timwi?tab=profile) for a Secret Santa puzzle exchange, themed around various custom modules for the game *Keep Talking and Nobody Explodes*. No KTaNE knowledge is necessary for any of these puzzles except the final meta; each puzzle resolves to a single word or short phrase.)</sup>

---

## On The Subject of Rubik's Cube

[image]

*(At one point, a word will be abbreviated in a puzzly way.)*

---

Hint:

> Just follow directions -- but where do they end?

Comment: So is this hint implying that @HTM was onto something?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe the answer is

> **ANDROID**

First, note that...

> ... each face is labeled on its center square: UP, DN, LF, RT, FT, BK.  When following instructions, use the first letter of these labels (i.e. U, D, L, R, F, and B), which correspond to standard cubing notation.
>
>  Also, in keeping with cubing notation, all rotations are clockwise; counterclockwise turns use a ' symbol, and none are present here.

Then...

> ... follow the arrow on the original cube, reading off as many squares as is shown in the first set below the cube, which is six.  This yields **DO ROTATE URDU**.
>
>  After following that instruction, following the arrow again, and reading seven squares, you get **DO ROT AYERS ROCK**.  In other words, DO ROT ULURU; [Uluru](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ayers_Rock) is another name for Ayers Rock.  (The "ROT" here is probably the "puzzly abbreviation".)
>
>  After following *that* instruction, following the arrow again, and reading nine squares, you get **DO KONAMI USE F AS A**.  In other words, use the [Konami code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konami_Code), but use F as A.  This yields DO UUDDLRLRBF.
>
>  After following *that* instruction, following the arrow once more, and reading off four squares, you get the answer, **ANDROID**.

Comment: Nicely done! There's something else disambiguating the lengths, though (and there shouldn't be an N in the final message).

Comment: I _just_ re-noticed the squares below the cube.  Revisiting...

Comment: @Deusovi Transcription error.  Thanks, Google Sheets cell autocomplete.

Comment: That's it, nicely done!